# Can i Dual boot Win 7 64 Bit with Ubuntu 32 Bit?

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, windows-7, 32-bit

I have a Windows 7 64 bit and now i am thinking to install Ubuntu 32 Bit on a separate partition as dual boot.Can i do that? Someone told me that I cannot dual boot a 64 bit and 32 bit OS as it can mess my hard drive. 
Please tell me is it true or a myth. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. I have had such configuration for about an year, and ran perfectly fine. Only thing was that I could use only 3 GB RAM out of available 4 GB in a 32 bit installation.

Comment: Max memory for 32 bits is 4 GB.. Why can't you use more than 3??

Answer (score 2):

This is a myth. **YOU CAN** dual boot with the given configuration.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can, simply install Ubuntu as you would.